# When is it possible to find a relatively prime pair among $n$ numbers?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Suppose I have a set of $n$ numbers and their gcd is $d$. If I divide every number by $d$, is it possible to find a pair that is relatively prime? Intuitively yes, but how do I prove it? I tried proceeding by contradiction, like what happens when there are no two numbers who don't share a divisor.

Answer (score 5):

You can't prove this because it's not true. Consider

$$\{6,10,15\}$$

The $\gcd$ of all of them is $1$, but there is no pair whose $\gcd$ is $1$.